# Shut down localhost address which is taken from asp.net by default

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

On windows 10, when I run `http://localhost`, it opens some `asp.net` project.

How can I shut down this?  because I need start wamp server but that address is already taken by `asp.net`

Sorry if this is dummy question, but I have no idea how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open IIS and click the stop button (on the right-hand side, under Actions/Manage Server).  Then start WAMP.